# Is there any javascript template library can work with webpack's i18n plugin?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, webpack

the __('string') function can not integrate with Handlebars file.

Is there any other library can work with __() function?

this is my *.handlebars file:

```
<div> __('title') </div>
```

and I am trying to i18n it.
and I am using handlebars-loader to require this file.
but seems webpack can not analyze the __() function in handlebars file.

the output html of the template is:

```
<div> __('title') </div>
```

what I want is:

```
<div>title</div>
```

or

```
<div>标题</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What are you trying to achieve with Handlebars exactly?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Just adapted based on [the example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/i18n):

```
var path = require('path');
var I18nPlugin = require('i18n-webpack-plugin');
var languages = {
    'en': null,
    'de': require('./de.json')
};
module.exports = Object.keys(languages).map(function(language) {
    return {
        name: language,
        entry: './templates/example.hbs',
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
            filename: language + '.output.js'
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.hbs$/,
                    loaders: ['handlebars'],
                    include: path.join(__dirname, 'templates')
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new I18nPlugin(
                languages[language]
            )
        ]
    };
});
```

Comment: Note that this outputs JS files you can then import through your code. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you wanted. If you need just html output like that, it may be better to go directly through Handlebars and skip Webpack in between. It all depends on how you want to consume the data. You can also push it to client side and so on.

Comment: Thanks anyway. The answer you provide is not exactly what I wanted. Using hbs as a entry point is not suit for me, I wanted to integrate __() function with templates. But your answer change the way I think about how to use webpack.

Comment: Can you describe the context where you use the templates? We could push the replacement logic to a loader but that would give us only single language defeating the idea of i18n. I feel you might need to do something dynamic outside of Webpack and apply the translations on client-side.

Comment: @Littlee: were you able to find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @AbhinavSingi Finally, I move to React, {__('yout text')} worked